# Saving and Reading data across computers

Tags: data

I DumpSaved some data from my home laptop, uploaded it onto google drive and now I am trying to open it at my school computer but I am getting errors, even though the data is in the correct directory. My data is bunch of data for different parameter values that I have stored as a function.

```
out[] := Cases[DownValues[out], _String, Infinity]
out[ToString[DataStep1[[l, 3]]]] = outNR
DumpSave["Renegotiation.mx", out]
<< Renegotiation.mx
```

The data can be found [here:](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4tcwo2ZvQCRNE1hTDJKdzJTZ1k/edit?usp=sharing)

The details of DumpSave says that "Files written by DumpSave can only be read on the same type of computer system on which they were written."

What is a "type of computer system" ? Both my laptops are PCs with windows. Is there no way for me to read my data at the school laptop? In any event, can you please suggest how I can store data that I can open on different computers?

Comment: A "type of computer system" is like a "kind" of animal in the book of Genesis... it means whatever someone wants it to mean in order for it to be a convenient excuse. :) Practically speaking, the platform, processor type (32- or 64-bit), and *Mathematica* version all need to match for the .mx files to be mutually intelligible. I'm not certain whether revision or build numbers matter as I haven't tested that but I would suspect revision does and build doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Save` - it works like DumpSave, except the output is not binary encoded, and is transportable from system to system, (different operating systems / Mathematica versions, to an extent).

```
out[] := Cases[DownValues[out], _String, Infinity]
out[ToString[DataStep1[[l, 3]]]] = outNR
Save["Renegotiation.sav", out]
<< Renegotiation.sav
```

Docs: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Save.html

NB c/w `DumpSave`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7896522/879601

Comment: WDX format is another option, arguably more useful if you want to preserve structures like packed arrays, images, and compressed objects (e.g. graphics) without having to translate them into their `FullForm` and back.

Comment: Chris: Thanks a lot for your answer!